# Fit Static Google Map API into a custom size without stretching

Tags: css, reactjs, google-maps

I am trying to create a banner-like feel to by using a custom google maps image for my pages. I am using react google maps with Maps Static API. The static map has a size of 640 x 355 hardcoded in the link.

I would like the map to take over to 100% of the width of the screen while only displaying the height of 216px, where the center of the map is the marker icon at coordinates position.

Currently what happens is the map either fits into the bounds, of its container 100% by 216px, but stretches itself, or it keeps it's original size without resizing. What is the best practice for rendering the map without stretching. Thanks!

```
  return (
                <main style={{  height: '216px' }}>
                   <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
                         <img alt={alt} src={src} width='100%' height="100%" />
                   </div>
                </main>
    )
```

where src is `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x355&scale=1&key=API_KEY&maptype=terrain&language=en&markers=icon:http://localhost:3000/icon.png|43.0439203,-112.414927&zoom=15&center=__CENTER__&format=png8&`

Comment: link you provided gives "The Google Maps Platform server rejected your request. The provided API key is invalid." can you download the image and upload/host it somewhere?

Comment: what happens when you change the size parameter of the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting the image with an absolute position?

You could do something like:

```html
<main style="height: 216px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <img alt={alt} src={src} style="height: 100%; width: auto; position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 0);" />
</main>
```

What you basically do here is you put the image inside the main container, you indicate it occupies 100% of the 216px height, you indicate the width is to be automatically calculated, you put it in an absolute position and center it horizontally.

Meanwhile the overflow allows the image to be cropped without changing dimensiones.

Is that what you want to achieve?

Other than that you can't achieve 100% screen width without the image scaling. You'd need to use Google Maps JavaScript API to make an interactive Google Maps for that and just center it on screen resize, but that's a totally different thing from what you are currently commenting.

**UPDATE REGARDING GOOGLE MAPS**

As for Google Maps you can start here: [Google Maps Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

I don't know if you already have an API key and a billing account but it might ask you for that. You must have an API key with the JavaScript Maps API enabled. And then you can use all the examples.

This is a very basic example I usually use on sites. You'll basically have an HTML like this, the CSS and JS parts can be of course moved to separate files you just have to be careful that when Google Maps's URL calls the callback function `initMap()` it's available to call, otherwise you'll get an error. You can also put the coordinates in variables and use the variables instead.

```html
<style>
    #map { width: 100%; height: 216px; position: relative; }
    #map > #map-canvas { min-height: 100%; }
</style>
<div id="map">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
<script>
    function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: { lat: 45.000001, lng: -90.000001 },
        disableDefaultUI: false,
        scrollwheel: false
    });

    var main_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.000001, -90.000001),
        map: map
    })

    // This is the function that centers your marker each time
    // the viewport gets resized so that the marker is always
    // in the middle
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(45.000001, -90.000001));
    });
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{your_api_key}}&language=en_US&callback=initMap" async></script>
<!-- you can change the language with the language parameter //-->
```

From what I understood this would basically solve your problem.

Comment: @minkov you're absolutely right. the code above was successful at centering the img, but when I set width: 100%, it stretches it. I will need to go with the interactivity of the map through image scaling. Could you help with resources on how to use Google Maps JS API for this?

Comment: @ksenia I edited my answer :) Please check the update. I think that would work for what you need.

Comment: Glad you liked the answer :) I suppose I got the bounty haha

Comment: yes, thank you! I can award it in 20 hours tho, so stay tuned:)

Comment: Cool! It's my first bounty that's why I didn't know those details. Good luck! @ksenia